# Connecting external GSM modem with android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, ril

Is it possible to connect the external GSM modem to the android emulator, so that the real RIL function can be observed?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can connect a GSM, but a lot of the functions (send SMS, receive calls) can be faked via the console through telnet.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#console